# Internet Explorer hanging when debugging ASP.NET app

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer

This problem is beginning to annoy.

After my machine (Vista Ultimate) has been up for a while, running my ASP.NET web site project for debugging in VS2008 results in Internet Explorer "hanging". It doesn't seem to get past the network access stage, you know when it says "Loading web site", or "Waiting for".

I've attached a screenshot of IE. Note the status bar. It stays like that forever. I have to restart it and cross my fingers for it to work the next time. Invariably, it doesn't.

This happened with IE7 and IE8.

I am using the ASP.NET Web Development Server/Cassini. I have tried restarting this each time which seemed ot have got it, but then not so any more.

I'm up to date on patches.

[ie screenshot http://img40.imageshack.us/img40/5446/iehanging.png](http://img40.imageshack.us/img40/5446/iehanging.png)

Comment: Do other browsers work? If they do, it's an IE problem, if they don't it's a web-server problem...

Comment: It works in Firefox. I'm keen to make it work in IE as that is my preferred browser when used with VS. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you just start the developement server (ctrl -F5) without attaching to the WebDeb.WebServer process ? If not, what happens if you manually attach to that process after just starting the server ?

Comment: Here's an interesting thing. When it fails under normal, I run it under no-debugging and it still may not work. When it doesn't work, closing IE re-opens a new IE and it bursts into life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So thankfully Microsoft have finally released Security Essentials.

This meant I could de-install AVG (Free and paid-for versions) from my machine.

Hey presto, it works!

Comment: Was there any conclusive evidence linking this to AVG? I might be seeing a similar problem, but not sure if I have to kill AVG right away or not.

Comment: The evidence was I got rid of it and it all worked perfectly. :)

Comment: I had the same problem and reached the same conclusion. I don't know if it's only happening with AVG or it's a general thing with web browsing protection, but after I disabled it everything worked smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

I would check the following

1) that your not starting IE against the webserver againt the wrong port, if your using the development IIS then it changes ports at times. That combined with you setting up the browser to launch against a the old port could create this problem.
2) Stop the local IIS and restart it (Again make sure your pointing towards the correct port)
3) Make sure you dont have any hung IE in task manager ( this happens to me sometimes ). Basiclly you have a IE in task manager that uses less then 1mb of ram and does not show on the taskbar, if thats the case kill them.

Comment: 1: Browsing to localhost on an unused port will not make the browser hang, just give you a "connection failed" message.

2: He is not using the local IIS.

Comment: Hi and Thanks, sorry for the delay. Sods law is if you want it to fail to check these out, it starts working. 1) The project has consistently run on 56125 ever since I started it and this remains the case. 2) Have started IIS, though I am using Cassini (which I have also tried restarting)? - no effect. 3) No hung processes of IE.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't sound, strictly speaking, like a hang.  Can that tab/other tabs be navigated to other sites?  Is your machine configured to use a proxy?

Is the request actually sent?  Using Fiddler2 from www.fiddler2.com with the URL http://ipv4.fiddler:56125/ will show you, and help determine where in IE the problem might be.

Comment: Using other tabs, even the URL bar to navigate anywhere (even public web sites) provides no joy. Still same "hang"/"staleness". I've never seen any local requests appear in Fiddler. I didn't know Fiddler respected local->local requests?

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar problem that took about a week to unravel. Using AVG 9 Business Edition.
I'm on a Windows 7 machine with Visual Studio 2010 SP1, debugging ASP.NET sites running in IIS, with the same "hang" behavior you're seeing. Disabling LinkScanner and Online Shield in AVG fixed the problem.